# How to format ag-grid columns individually?(Ag-grid react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

Documentation: https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/

let's consider that the ag-grid table has 5 columns with colId of 't1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5'.

How do I format each column such that when the user pastes values(1 2 3 4 5) in the first row and clicks enter, the values should automatically go to thier respective rows.

Ex: User pastes 1 2 3 4 5 in first row of first column(t1).

The first value(1) is the data in first row of first column.

The second value(2) is the data in second row of first column.
and so on..

The first column should look like

```
t1

1
2
3
4
5
```

How can this be done?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this requirement. Pasting data shouldn't require the user to press `ENTER`. Do you mean pasting the data into a Cell Editor and then hitting `ENTER`?

Comment: Yes, pasting data into first cell and hit enter

Comment: Asking again, do you mean cell editor? Pasting into a cell, and pasting into a cell editor are different things.

Comment: What do you mean by cell editor? Is it the cell that is being edited?

Comment: When you double click on a Cell and a text field show up, that's a cell editor. When you simply select a cell and paste values, that's Clipboard interaction. Both sections can be seen here: 
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/cell-editing/#example-cell-editing or  https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/clipboard/

We need to know which one you are talking about, because the solution would be different.

Comment: ohh, since clipboard is paid version I was looking to make my own clipboard version manually. The functionality is similar to how clipboard interaction works but using cell editing.